# How to modify object knowing memory adress in c++?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, memory-management

Good evening.

I opened Visual Studio 2012 and run program doing this:

```
    double x = 8768130;
    cout << &x;

    cin.get();
    return 0;
```

Address it wrote in console was `003CFBF8`.

Then, I opened another copy of Visual Studio and tried to read this, but I am not sure if I am doing it correctly. I was already searching in Stack Overflow before posting it and find out that I should do something like that:

```
    double* ptr = reinterpret_cast<double*>(0x003CFBF8);

    cout << *ptr;
```

but it produced exception

`Unhandled exception at 0x00A943DD in Project2.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x003CFBF8.`

What does that mean?  I have no access? I did it in wrong way?

If you ask me why I want to do that, I am learning C++ from some of books and I wanted to check how `volatile` works. This is why I wanted to:

> - open first program, initialize variable, write it's address;
> - open second program and modify what written address relates to
> - write variable in first program to check if everything is okay.

Comment: Modern platforms so some virtual memory address randomization (mainly for security reasons). Besides that, there is nothing to say that the address of a literal constant should be the same in different processes. So it could simply be that in your second run, the address is somewhere you're not allowed to read from.

Comment: The first program is still running: it is waiting for me because of ` cin.get();`, then I open second program to modify the address. Or it does not matter?

Comment: In that case, it is even simpler (and answered by @jonathonReinhart.)

Comment: Is there a way to make it "external", that I can modify it? From what I understood, if I do it in the same program, it doesn't matter if I use ` volatile `, because complier will be knowing that I modify the value of ` x `. I would want to do this that 'he' won't notice and the simplest solution I thought will be just opening another copy of VS2012 :)

Comment: @Kusavil Again, **no**, not from another process. You can modify it from your same process (potentially from another *thread*), or using the debugging APIs.

Comment: A tear runs my face as the OP reminds me of myself and those experiments in my early days of programming :') GO FOR IT!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> ... I opened another copy of Visual Studio ...

and there lies your problem.  All modern systems use [*virtual memory*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory), which means one process is not allowed to touch another process's *virtual address space*.  This is enforced by the processor.

You could *potentially* do this within the same process (program).  However, modern OSes also enable ASLR (Address Space Layout Randomization) which means that a piece of code or data will likely load at a different virtual address, every time the program is executed.

If you want to access the memory of another process, your best bet is probably to use your OS's [debugging APIs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679303.aspx). Specifically, on Windows you can call [`WriteProcessMemory`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681674.aspx).

If you just want to play with `volatile` (where memory might change out from underneath you), you should consider spawning another *thread*, who periodically modifies a globablly-accessible variable.

Comment: Can I somehow make it "public", that it will be possible to read this? Or enforce it somehow? Or write it in some other way?

Comment: Inter-process communication or other client-server design might be appropriate. But since we don't know what you are really trying to do with this value, hard to tell what might be best.

Comment: @Kusavil you can export your variable and find it from another process with GetProcAddress()

Comment: @Nighthawk441 That is completely incorrect.  You **cannot** directly access the memory of another process.

Comment: @Jonathon Reinhart it depends on what he wants to do, which he didn't really specify.

Comment: @Nighthawk441 No, it does not depend. I repeat, *you **cannot** directly access the memory of another process.* No amount of C constructs will change that.  You can call `GetProcAddress` all you want, and you're not going to change the memory of another running process.

Comment: @Nighthawk441 The debugging APIs, yes.

Comment: Thank you, I will try to learn something more about threads and debugging functions :)